# add active class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
         <ul>            
            <li id="db" onclick="loadSlide('db_content')">Database</li>                
            <li id="xp" onclick="loadSlide('xp_content')">Xpath</li>
            <li id="con" onclick="loadSlide('con_content')">Controller</li>
        </ul>
```

This is the code and I want to add active class.
Please note that there is no a tag.
Now how can I add active class to li
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean with active class?

Comment: Are you talking about pseudo classes?

Comment: I want that when user click on Databas so this should be active I mean it's bg-color should change and when user click on Xpath so Databas's color go back to default color and Xpath got bg-color

Comment: If you can clarify your question by editing, please feel free to flag it for moderator review.

Comment: I think he means CSS style classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more relative and reliable.

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('someClassName');
})
```

Comment: @bitsmix point, yes its good write as follows, $('.someClassName').remove('someClassName'); becase once you clicked, the class will remain even you click other list item.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didnt understand that what do you mean with active class but you can use this for adding class to an element

```
$('li').addClass('someClassName');
```

Comment: Add an active class to each `li`? That wouldn't be too helpful, would it?

Comment: yes it would not work to add class to each li
I want that when user click on Databas so this should be active I mean it's bg-color should change and when user click on Xpath so Databas's color go back to default color and Xpath got bg-color

Answer (score 0):

according to your comment earlier:

```
   $("ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('activeClass');
        $(this).addClass('activeClass');
   });
```

and define the style in `someClass`.

Comment: It is adding active class to all li when I click on each li and not removing back active class